# Защита от XSS и обратный слеш

Tags: php, javascript, база-данных, безопасность, xss

На клиенте перед отправкой на сервер отсекаю практически всё за исключением русского, украинского и белорусского шрифтов. Делаю это в первую очередь чтобы пользователь сразу понимал, какие символы он ввести не может.

```
data = data.replace(/[^\w\n\" а-яА-ЯёЁA-Za-zÀ-ÿёа-зй-шы-яЁА-ЗЙ-ШЫІіЎўа-щА-ЩЬьЮюЯяЇїІіЄєҐґ'-,.:!?@«»]/ig, '');
```

Обработанные строки заносятся в объект и преобразуются в строку:

```
obj = JSON.stringify(obj);
```

С целью защиты от **XSS** проверяю данные на сервере, при этом строка не разбирается перед записью в БД, но проверяется целиком:

```
$obj = preg_replace("/[^\w\"\n а-яА-ЯёЁA-Za-zÀ-ÿёа-зй-шы-яЁА-ЗЙ-ШЫІіЎўа-щА-ЩЬьЮюЯяЇїІіЄєҐґ',-.!?@{{}}:«»]/iu", "", $obj) ;
```

Проблема: если на клиенте в тексте встречаются двойные кавычки, они экранируются обратным слешем при `JSON.stringify(obj)`, а уже на сервере обратный слеш отрезается при `preg_replace`, после чего строку вновь преобразовать в объект при чтении уже нельзя.

Я вижу несколько вариантов решения:

1. Не удалять слеш изначально, поскольку в сочетании с оставшимися символами использовать его для атаки нельзя (так ли это?).
2. Санировать данные на сервере не при записи, а при чтении из БД (в этом случае    дополнительный расход ресурсов, поскольку чтение происходит гораздо чаще записи в моём случае).
3. Разбирать построчно на сервере, а перед записью вновь собирать в строку (также расход ресурсов).
4. С помощью регулярного выражения отслеживать и оставлять последовательность `\"`.

Прошу совета, как лучше поступить в этой ситуации.

Comment: Защита от XSS на клиенте эквивалентна отсутствию защиты. Все проверки и экранирования должны быть на сервере и только на сервере!

Comment: А ваша текущая серверная проверка может сломать JSON и, весьма вероятно, всё ещё уязвима для XSS. Вы должны просто передать с клиента данные как есть, а на сервере всё разобрать и проверить, а не как сейчас

Comment: На клиенте проверка делается в том числе с целью дать понимание пользователю, что именно он ввести не может. Это не столько защита, сколько, скорее usability. А вот действительно защита, да - только на сервере. Разобрать и проверить это один из рассматриваемых вариантов. Возможно, рабочие и другие, о чем спрашиваю совета. P.S. Уточню текст вопроса.

Comment: И, кстати, защита от XSS путём выкидывания запрещённых символов — обычно плохая практика. Что если я использую типографскую раскладку с кавычками-«ёлочками» и тире — всё, меня заставят писать неправильную пунктуацию? А если я хочу Emoji? 

Comment: Это не чат и не развлекательный ресурс, emoji просто не понадобятся в моём случае. Какая практика защиты от XSS хорошая кроме оставления заведомо безопасных символов? Буду признателен за совет.

Comment: Единственно правильная практика — просто экранировать небезопасные символы по ситуации. Любой нормальный HTML-шаблонизатор поддерживает экранирование HTML-спецсимволов из коробки. mysqli и PDO автоматически экранируют кавычки при использовании подготовленных выражений и защищают от SQL-инъекций.

Comment: Спасибо за совет. PDO использую, но оно не защитит от xss, но только от инъекции БД, насколько я понимаю. HTML-шаблонизатор мне сможет помочь на бекэнде?

Comment: Шаблонизатор должен присутствовать на любом нормальном сайте, ибо стандарт, сильно упрощающий жизнь разработчику. Если вы не можете или не хотите его использовать, всегда есть htmlspecialchars

Comment: htmlspecialchars используется. В текущей ситуации что вы посоветуете с учетом заданных вопросов?

Comment: Если htmlspecialchars используется, то зачем вообще что-то ещё?

Comment: @118_64 тут не следует изобретать, а принять общую концепцию: каждая переменная фильтруется отдельно в PHP, если это требуется. Это очень лихо и удобно делается с фреймворками: большинство переменных не надо фильтровать вовсе. Для того что потом попадёт в html есть функция `strip_tags`, или можно нагуглить более сложные функции, которые фильтруют html от любых скриптов и их проявлений. Переменные для `select` запросов в БД можно вовсе не фильтровать, если для их построения вы используете построители или PDO (где переменная аргументом передаётся, а не слепляется в строке)